# How does `FirestoreAdminClient.exportDocuments` create the timestamp on a folder in Firebase when exporting?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Google Firebase provides a manual for exporting firebase data, here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export

The main function run is below. From this, a time-stamped folder under `BUCKET_NAME` is created with the example format:

```
2020-05-12T17:55:41_69705
```

I would like to create custom backups that still retain the format of the time stamp. I went all over github but was unable to find the function creating this specific time stamp. Does anyone have any ideas? I assumed it is something inside `firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient.exportDocuments`.

```
const firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();
// Replace BUCKET_NAME
const bucket = 'gs://BUCKET_NAME'

exports.scheduledFirestoreExport = (event, context) => {
  const databaseName = client.databasePath(
    process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
    '(default)'
  );

  return client
    .exportDocuments({
      name: databaseName,
      outputUriPrefix: bucket,
      // Leave collectionIds empty to export all collections
      // or define a list of collection IDs:
      // collectionIds: ['users', 'posts']
      collectionIds: [],
    })
    .then(responses => {
      const response = responses[0];
      console.log(`Operation Name: ${response['name']}`);
      return response;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any documentation about this, but it seems that the Firebase Storage export will automatically create this exact timestamp name for you in the backend if you don't provide a folder name.

You can however disable this behavior by providing your own folder name. This will put your data in a folder called `myfoldername` and not create the timestamped folder:

```
  return client
    .exportDocuments({
      name: databaseName,
      outputUriPrefix: bucket + "/myfoldername",
      // Leave collectionIds empty to export all collections
      // or define a list of collection IDs:
      // collectionIds: ['users', 'posts']
      collectionIds: [],
    })
    .then(responses => {
      const response = responses[0];
      console.log(`Operation Name: ${response['name']}`);
      return response;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
```

I needed to do this so that I could clone the Cloud Storage folder to my Windows PC, as Windows doesn't seem to allow folder names to contain colons `:`, and this broke the download.